# ASP.NET MVC3: custom [authorise] attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security, attributes

In my database, the system user has a list of modules he/she can access.

I would like to be able to add an authorise attribute which checks that this is the case.

E.g. `[authorise(UserID, ControllerName)]`

Which goes to some code, ensures that the User with UserID specified, has the controller name in his/her list.

At the moment you can simply bypass the fact the tabs aren't visible, by using the URL. (I have code which already checks if the user has specified access and hides/shows tabs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string currentUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        string currentController = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");

        // TODO: go hit your database and see if currentUser can access
        // currentController and return true/false from here

        ...
    }
}
```

then decorate your controllers or actions:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public class FooController: Controller
{
    ...
}
```

---

This being said I suspect that you might have gone the wrong way in your database design by storing a list of which user has access to access which controller action. Probably you should have used roles for that. Having the database know about controllers just feels wrong.

So:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Foo,Bar")]
public class FooController: Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Only users that have the `Foo` or `Bar` role can access the `FooController`.

Comment: If you want to pass the values in yourself, then just add the properties UserID and ControllerName to Darin's class. Then access your [MyAuthorize(UserID = xx, ControllerName = "xxx")].

Comment: Any way to redirect them to Home/index? Apart from that, works great. thanks! The names of the controllers arent in the database, but a corrosponding module key is. Its a webfront for an existing app/database, so am forced to use the current structure.

Comment: @Doomsknight, sure, just change the login url in your web.config. Or if you want more fine grained control over what does the attribute do if it authentication fails you could override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }


        bool authorized = // Perform custom logic

        If(!authorized)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(/* Your access denied url */);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the model, check the permission

```
DisplayAdminLink = _permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.AccessAdminPanel),
```

and in the view

```
    @if (Model.DisplayAdminLink)
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/admin")" class="ico-admin">@T("Account.Administration")</a>
        </li>
    }
```